# an error when starting kafka server in linux ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a problem in starting kafka server.
So when I run the command

% bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

I get the following error.
Any help
Thank you

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abdelkader/work/hbase-1.2.6/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abdelkader/work/hbase-1.2.6/lib/phoenix-4.12.0-HBase-1.2-hive.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abdelkader/work/hbase-1.2.6/lib/phoenix-4.12.0-HBase-1.2-pig.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abdelkader/work/hbase-1.2.6/lib/phoenix-4.12.0-HBase-1.2-thin-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abdelkader/work/hbase-1.2.6/lib/phoenix-4.12.0-HBase-1.2-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abdelkader/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[2021-02-19 03:53:38,432] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2021-02-19 03:53:38,502] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/Properties;
    at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:51)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ok, I have solved my problem by performing some cleaning in my .bashrc file, commenting some activated services along with jar lib files. I think there was some mismatchings.